# Should an Access Token be renewed for every call using JWT?

Tags: soql, javascript, oauth2, jwt, accesstoken

Using the **OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow**, when does the **Access Token** need to be **renewed**?

Let's say the **JWT Flow** is used to send **queries** to **Salesforce** from time to time.

Should one request a new **Access Token** for every time a **query** is sent?

Or should one store the **Access Token** for some time and **re-fetch** a new one when it expires, like with **Refresh Tokens**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce restricts logins to an average of [one per second](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381578&type=1). It is strongly recommended that you keep your access token until you receive an HTTP 401 status code or the expiry time is reached.